# mostrar el valor de una clave si la otra clave es verdadera en una lista de diccionarios en Python

Tags: python-3.x

tengo una lista de diccionarios y necesito devolver el valor de la clave 'spName' que tenga el valor 'true' en la clave 'assigned'

```
diccionario = [{'spName': 'basic', 'assigned': 'false'},
{'spName': 'premium', 'assigned': 'true'},
{'spName': 'colaboracion', 'assigned': 'false'},
{'spName': 'complete', 'assigned': 'false'}
]
```

En este ejemplo la salida deberia ser:

```
premium
```

Estoy usando Python 3.6
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: `salida = [x['spName'] for x in diccionario if x['assigned'] == 'true']`

Comment: @aeportugal Excelente! muchas gracias por tu ayuda.